# longtext in select makes query extremely slow

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I am having a plain flat table with below structure

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_pipeline_logging` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source` TEXT,
  `comments` TEXT,
  `data` LONGTEXT,
  `query` TEXT,
  `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In this table I basically log all my error from where ever i get in the code. 
Now the `data` column in the above table is defined as `longtext` and currently I am having data in this column with almost `32Mb size` for each record.

So now when i am going with the plain select query its taking alot of time to fetch the results.

eg:-

```
SELECT * FROM oc_pipeline_logging limit 10
```

In-fact when i am running the above query in the terminal i am getting below error

```
mysql> SELECT COMMENTs,DATA FROM oc_pipeline_logging WHERE id = 18;
ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

But the same is running fine in sqlYog but taking lot of time.
How can I execute this query faster and fetch my rows quickly?

Comment: Do you need the longtext column every time? It may be worth using a separate query to retrieve that only when needed?

Comment: No , I dont need it every time . But whenever i need the column its too slow to fetch the result .

Comment: Infact it takes 3 secs approx to fetch only single record.

Comment: max_allowed_packet=2048M worked or not??

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same at my end getting such type of error.
But there could be a solution to increase the memory limit in `my.ini`.

```
max_allowed_packet=2048M
```

You can change the limit accordingly, Hope this will resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi I have already tried this but this dint solve my problem of speeding up my select . Appreciate your response.